# How do I create a custom control that accepts <Run/> text?

Tags: c#, wpf

Given the control below, how do I modify it to accept "Run" text?

Custom Control:

```
[ContentProperty("Text")]
public class GradientTitle : Control
{
    public GradientTitle()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(GradientTitle);
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(GradientTitle), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

Intended use:

```
        <customControls:GradientTitle>
                <Run Text="The quick brown fox" />
                <Run Text="jumps over the lazy dog" />
                <Run Text="{Binding SomeText}" />
        </customControls:GradientTitle>
```

Comment: Probably in the same way the TextBlock control does, create an [`Inlines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.inlines.aspx) property. And then write all the code that does the formatting and display.

Comment: why reinventing  the wheel

Comment: Because an InlineCollection instance cannot be created the same way TextBlock control does it. Additionally, if you create it with a getter only, WPF will return 'Cannot create an instance of "InlineCollection"'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably shouldn't do this, as `TextBlock` already does it, but anyway:

```
[ContentProperty("Inlines")]
[TemplatePart(Name = "PART_InlinesPresenter", Type = typeof(TextBlock))]
public class GradientTitle : Control
{
    private readonly Collection<Inline> _inlines = new Collection<Inline>();

    public Collection<Inline> Inlines
    {
        get { return _inlines; }
    }

    static GradientTitle()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(GradientTitle),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(GradientTitle)));
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.ApplyTemplate();

        var inlinesPresenter = GetTemplateChild("PART_InlinesPresenter") as TextBlock;
        if(inlinesPresenter != null)
        {
            var targetInlines = inlinesPresenter.Inlines;
            foreach(var inline in Inlines)
            {
                targetInlines.Add(inline);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To simplify solution, I'm using `TextBlock` to render inline objects and declaring `Inlines` as a simple (non-dependency) property (almost as `TextBlock` does - it's `Inlines` property is not bindable without some external help). Also I don't track any collection changes. All these missing features can be added if needed, but require too much code for a simple answer.

Usage in XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <FrameworkElement.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:GradientTitle}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:GradientTitle}">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="PART_InlinesPresenter" />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </FrameworkElement.Resources>
    <customControls:GradientTitle>
        <Run Text="TEST1" />
        <LineBreak />
        <Run Text="TEST2" />
        <LineBreak />
        <Run Text="{Binding Path=Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
    </customControls:GradientTitle>
</Grid>
```

Obviously, style can be declared somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks max, you saved the day.